# Is there scientific evidence that spacing out vaccines have any positive effects?

Tags: vaccination, infectious-diseases, microbiology

There are parents and doctors that agree to spread out their kids' shots. Supposedly it's easier on the baby (some babies experience fever or other ill reactions to vaccination).

But I had a thought that maybe the fever after a certain shot might be the same regardless if it's taken together with another shot or not. Or maybe the ill effect even increases as the break between shots gets reduced and there is less time for body to recover for the next shots?

Is there any evidence that taking shots one by one reduces the ill effects?

Comment: The schedule is reviewed on a regular basis using all available data and studies, including reported adverse effects. I can't find the actual studies behind the current recommendations (Or I would post as an answer), but most recommend the schedule as too early/late will reduce effectiveness. Followup reading: https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/acip-recs/general-recs/timing.html https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/schedules/hcp/imz/child-adolescent.html https://www.aap.org/en-us/advocacy-and-policy/Documents/Vaccineschedule.pdf

Answer (score 6):

There is evidence that delaying or refusing immunization puts children at risk of disease [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/19482753/) and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/20048244/). There is also [evidence](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=24843064) that delaying or spreading out MMR or MMRV in particular puts children at greater risk of reactions (febrile seizures), rather then reducing the risk. I'm not aware of any study demonstrating the opposite.

Comment: Correct. The only one I am sure about is a minuscule increase in risk of febrile seizure if you administer the combined single shot with both MMR+Varicella instead of two separate shots of MMR and Varicella (even if given in the same leg at the same time!) but that's in a very narrow age group. MOST spacing out of vaccines is done simply for patient/parent preference, so as not to have to endure so many pokes in one visit.  I will find the reference for that...  I have this conversation often. Evidence points to (and I'm all for) getting then done as soon as eligible & build protection ASAP.

Comment: @DoctorWhom re: MMRV, if I recall, the evidence was that the increased risk of febrile seizures was the relative risk of the combination vaccine vs. MMR and Varicella in two separate injections, and is more of any issue with that vaccine than with the schedule.

Comment: @Narusan and DeNovo - Perhaps I wasn't clear enough - that was intended to further emphasize that the schedule is usually followed at earliest eligible date, when not it's just for parent preference not because of evidence, and there is next to zero reason for spacing out vaccines.  I am 110% for getting vaccinated for everything possible.  Should I delete my comment if it is distracting?

Comment: @Narusan yes, it's been a while since my peds rotation, but young kids are most definitely afraid of going to the doctor because of shots. I remember being afraid myself, and that was quite some time ago. I only meant to say we have to be careful when we talk about these things. You don't want someone saying: "I'm not going to vaccinate my kids because Narusan said vaccines cause a life long fear of doctors".

Comment: @DeNovo True. I have “retracted” my comments. Bottom line: The only halfway sensible reason to spread vaccinations out is if children/patients severely object and can’t be calmed and you would risk life-long traumatization instead. In that way, it might be sensible to give the child space to retreat and try again in a different approach - but that’s obviously not supposed to be a few months later!

Comment: I honestly think that lifelong traumatizing is a RARE phenomenon.  Kids who are afraid of the doctor seem to grow out of it after age 5 or so.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Yeah, that’s why I’ve deleted a fair bunch of comments. On the other hand, it seems to be used as an excuse for not doing regular checkups, at least of the patients I’ve been exposed to the past 3 months...